# Put not working using Poster

Tags: json, netsuite, poster

I am most likely doing something wrong but not sure what. I am trying to test a NetSuite Restlet (web service) using FF poster. I can use Get to work by passing data in the URL. However, I get an error using the Put method.

**{"error" : {"code" : "SYNTAX_ERROR", "message" : "SyntaxError: Empty JSON string (null$lib#3)."}}**

It's hitting my catch block below. I read that to create or update we should use Put so not sure why Get works but not Put?

```
function CreateRecord(jsonobject)
{
    try
    {
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', '  in get =  ');

        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonobject)
        nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'JSON', jsonString);

        // Mandatory
        var name = jsonobject["name"];
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', '  name =  ', name);

        var record = nlapiCreateRecord('customrecordtest');
        record.setFieldValue('name', name);
        var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'id  =  ', id);
        return jsonobject;
    }
    catch (err) 
    {
        nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'Error', err.message);       
        return err.message;
    } 
}
```

Poster:

https://rest.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=351&deploy=1&name=Restlet Test

Comment: Can you add your Restlet code??

Comment: Sure. I've condensed it to make it more readable.

Comment: From the error it much seems like the error caused due to an invalid JSON. Please check the JSON which you're sending as playload for your PUT method

Comment: But that would mean the Get should also fail?

Comment: Do your log statements all log what you expect?

Comment: Using Get, yes. It logs everything. The poster returns status 200 OK. And it prints back my json object

Comment: But not when using PUT? My guess is that in your PUT request, your request body is `null`, so you are trying to access properties on `null` and you eventually return a `null` object, which is the error you're receiving.

Comment: A PUT request will not look for data in the URL. It will look for JSON in the body of the request itself. So instead of `&name=Restlet Test`, you will need to send an object in the body of the request like `{ "name" : "Restlet Test" }`

Comment: Ah ok, so using Put it logs nothing. Gives a syntax error - empty json string. So I guess using poster I need to pass the data within the body? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I would guess it's just the big text box at the bottom (looking at a screenshot of Poster). Just put JSON directly in there.

Comment: Perfect - all working. Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PUT request will not look for data in the URL. It will look for JSON in the body of the request itself. So instead of `&name=Restlet Test`, you will need to send an object in the body of the request like `{ "name" : "Restlet Test" }`